# VSCode highlight text and wrap in parenthesis or bracket

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can someone help me figure out which VSCode setting allows this behavior? Something changed in my settings after a recent upgrade and I can't figure out what it was:

1. Select text
2. Type `(`
3. Observe that the selected text is now wrapped in an opening and closing parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

The setting ID that deals with this feature is editor.autoSurround.
It can be found in the text editor settings.

Comment: thanks, but that looks to only specify quotes/brackets, when all of those used to work. I wonder why the default ("languageDefined") isn't working anymore...